# QT android make returns cannot find -lc++

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, qt, clang

I'm on Pop!_OS (ubuntu based distro) running Qt creator 4.9.2 with Qt 5.13.0 and am currently trying to build an app for android. When I try to build my app for desktop I have no error, but when I try to build it for Android the Make command returns a `error: cannot find -lc++`.
I also tried running one of the basics Qt example but I got the same response.

Any idea what I need to do to make it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the qt forums, Don't know why I din't think about looking there first...

Turns out on the NDK 20 you need to add an extra flag in the qmake.conf file.
It is shown here : 
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/264903/9/mkspecs/android-clang/qmake.conf#34

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been looking for this for the past few days